# vba: catching a file not found exception with DIR

Tags: excel, vba

i am using DIR to open a file:

```
If Dir("some dir" + "some file", vbNormal) <> "" The
End If
```

if the DIR does not exist then i get an exception BAD filename or number; However if the dir exists then this IF statement works fine.

**question** how do exception handle in a case where the DIR does not exist?

Comment: What is "some dir" likely to be? The above code run as is, in spite of using + to concatenate rather than &, does not produce the stated error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public Function IsADirectory(ByVal TheName As String) As Boolean
  If GetAttr(TheName) And vbDirectory Then
    IsADirectory = True
  End If
End Function
```

how about this ?

Answer (score 0):

The following code handles the case of the target not existing:

```
Public Function IsADirectory(ByVal TheName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim theResult As Boolean
    theResult = GetAttr(TheName) And vbDirectory
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        IsADirectory = theResult
    Else
        MsgBox "The target is not found."
    End If
End Function
```